# How to override DEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION?

Tags: ros2, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I build things with colcon I see compiler invocations like this:

```
g++ -DDEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp ...
```

I would like to override that preprocessor definition. How do I do that? Something like this has no effect:

```
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp
```

On a Ubuntu 20.04 host with foxy installed, this is the only file that mentions `DEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION`:

```
$ grep -rl 'DEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION' /opt/ros/foxy
/opt/ros/foxy/share/rmw_implementation/cmake/rmw_implementationExport.cmake
```

Within that file, here is the section that sets the `CPPFLAGS`:

```
$ grep -nC2 'DEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION' /opt/ros/foxy/share/rmw_implementation/cmake/rmw_implementationExport.cmake
55-
56-set_target_properties(rmw_implementation::rmw_implementation PROPERTIES
57:  INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "DEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp"
58-  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "rcpputils::rcpputils;rcutils::rcutils;rmw::rmw"
59-)
```

Here is the package that provides that file:

```
$ dpkg -S /opt/ros/foxy/share/rmw_implementation/cmake/rmw_implementationExport.cmake
ros-foxy-rmw-implementation: /opt/ros/foxy/share/rmw_implementation/cmake/rmw_implementationExport.cmake
```

Here is the version of that package at the time of this writing:

```
$ apt-cache policy ros-foxy-rmw-implementation
ros-foxy-rmw-implementation:
  Installed: 1.0.3-1focal.20220922.205522
  Candidate: 1.0.3-1focal.20220922.205522
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.3-1focal.20220922.205522 500
        500 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Short of changing the content of this `*.cmake` file for this package, how do I change the default rmw implementation definition used by the preprocessor?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407949/how-to-override-default_rmw_implementation-?/) by [realtime-neil](https://answers.ros.org/users/118515/realtime-neil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2022-10-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

AFAIK, you cannot change the default used by `ros-foxy-rmw-implementation`, as it's hard-coded into the `.cmake` file you already found.

The way this was implemented (not by me) is that *at build time* of `rmw_implementation`, the `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` environment variable is checked, and if set, it gets used ([here](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_implementation/blob/8c3c133eb070a4f19259f027cc2cea720b28eff0/rmw_implementation/CMakeLists.txt#L62-L63)) to populate a `target_compile_definitions(... DEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=...)` for the `rmw_implementation` target (which then gets `install(... export ...)`-ed later on, resulting in the `rmw_implementationExport.cmake` file you found).

That file is used/loaded by `rmw_implementation_cmake` ([here](https://github.com/ros2/rmw/blob/b635eec56ab3841965f2c1db39e0143d51304c79/rmw_implementation_cmake/cmake/get_default_rmw_implementation.cmake) fi) to determine which value it should return in case the `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` environment variable isn't set.

While you probably have your reasons, I must point out the intended way for this to be used is to set the `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` environment variable before starting any nodes. Regardless of what the value of `DEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` is, the RMW corresponding to `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` will be loaded (unless the `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION_DISABLE_RUNTIME_SELECTION` CMake option of `rmw_implementation` was set when it was built).

Note also that AFAIK, setting `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` at build time will *not* affect anything other than the value returned by CMake functions like `get_default_rmw_implementation(..)` and the value passed to the compiler. There don't appear to be any other code paths taken or code excluded or included based on that value anywhere in the core packages (in other words: the core ROS 2 packages will behave exactly the same, whether or not you set that variable, as all RMWs are loaded at runtime anyway, including any default, if configured).

Having written that: the direct answer to your question would seem to be: you can change the value which ends up in `DEFAULT_RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` by setting the `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` environment variable during the build of the `rmw_implementation` package. You might also be able to pass the value to CMake as a `--cmake-arg` using `-DRMW_IMPLEMENTATION=...` ([this](https://github.com/ros2/rmw_implementation/blob/8c3c133eb070a4f19259f027cc2cea720b28eff0/rmw_implementation/CMakeLists.txt#L37-L42) seems to suggest that). This would make it somewhat more manageable, as CMake args can be more easily stored in files.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-10-15**:
This was also discussed in [Change the default DDS implementation](https://discourse.ros.org/t/change-the-default-dds-implementation/2813/2) on ROS Discourse, which seems like it answers your question as well. I took the time to add some more detail and link to some of the files involved.